# Label boxes in ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like a label to appear above each box in a boxplot generated by `ggplot2`.

For example:

```
#Example data
test = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
patient = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
result =  c(5, 7, 2 ,4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 5, 6, 2 ,3)
data <- tibble(test, patient, result)

#Labels I want to include
Alabs = c(1, 3, 500)
Blabs = c(8, 16, -32)

#Plot data
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(patient), y = result, color = factor(test))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 1)
```

Gives the plot:

[image]

I would like to print the first element of `Alabs` above the red box for the first patient, the second element of `Alabs` above the red box for the second patient, the first element of `Blabs` above the blue box for the first patient, etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a separate labels dataset for adding the labels.

```
labs = tibble(test = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 3),
                  patient = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                  labels = c(1, 3, 500, 8, 16, -32) )

   test patient labels
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1     A       1      1
2     A       2      3
3     A       3    500
4     B       1      8
5     B       2     16
6     B       3    -32
```

The above contains all the information about the x axis and the faceting variable.  What it's missing is info about the location of the text on y axis.  To put these above the boxes we could calculate the max for each factor combinations plus a small value for the y position (while `geom_text` has a useful `nudge_y` argument, it doesn't work while dodging).

I make the summaries per group via *dplyr*, and then join the y position values to the labels dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

labeldat = data %>%
     group_by(test, patient) %>%
     summarize(ypos = max(result) + .25 ) %>%
     inner_join(., labs)
```

Now you can add the `geom_text` layer, using the dataset of labels.  To dodge these the same way as the boxplots, using `position_dodge`.  To keep letters from showing up in the legend I use `show.legend = FALSE`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(patient), y = result, color = test)) + 
     geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 1) +
     geom_text(data = labeldat, aes(label = labels, y = ypos), 
               position = position_dodge(width = .75), 
               show.legend = FALSE )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Takes some cheating to get the labels into the same tibble:

```
data$labs=c(NA, 1, NA, 3, NA, 500, NA, 8, NA, 16, NA, -32) #line up the labels so each patient gets one: if you put the NAs first, labels will be at the bottom of the boxes
data$lab_x=c(NA, 0.75, NA, 1.75, NA, 2.75, NA, 1.25, NA, 2.25, NA, 3.25) #set x position for each one
```

Then run `ggplot`:

```
 ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(patient), y = result, color = factor(test))) + 
   geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 1)+
   geom_text(aes(label=labs, x=lab_x))
```

[image]