# How to insert Cohen's d in the boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, ggpubr

Data are as follows:

```
   d <- data.frame(
        Class= rep(c('First', 'Second'), 10),
        Response= rnorm(20,14,4)
    )
```

Here is my codes to get the boxplots and Cohen's d:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(effsize)
p <- ggboxplot(d, x = "Class", y = "Response",
               color = "Class", palette = "jco",
               add = "jitter")
p + stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")
with(d, cohen.d(Response,Class))
```

I want to use only my codes to add Cohen's d to the boxplot.

Here is the intended outcome

[image]

Comment: Since it's also based on `ggplot2`, I'd think that https://stackoverflow.com/q/44833527/3358272 might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it all within the `ggpubr` framework, you can try:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(effsize)

ggboxplot(d, x = "Class", y = "Response", color = "Class", palette = "jco",
         add = "jitter") +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", 
        aes(label = paste0("t-test p = ",after_stat(p.adj),
              "; Cohen's D = ",
              with(d, round(cohen.d(Response,Class)$estimate, 3)))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Very many thanks, I am not sure why I get this error in my actual data Caused by error in `after_stat(p.adj) + "; Cohen's D = "`:non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: That should be a comma - you seem to have a plus sign. Please just copy / paste my code into your console - it's fully reproducible with the data set you included.

Comment: Error in `stat_compare_means()`:
! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics.
i Error occurred in the 3rd layer. and now  object 'Response' not found

Comment: @user330 do you still have the data frame called `d` that you created for the example in your global workspace? Have you perhaps changed it?

Comment: You are completely right and I am sorry. I have upvoted. Thank you